# Is this a bad way to implement a timer?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and one of the things I thought I'd do to practice is implement a timer in the browser. When looking at countdowns/timers I always saw people using getDate() and getTime() methods, but these kinda confused me so I implemented it this way. I'm just curious if this code is bad.

```
s = 0;

function countDown(){
   t = 60*25;
   s++;
   t -= s;
   var pomMins = Math.floor(t / 60);
   var pomSecs = t % 60;    

   if (t > 0){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "" + pomMins + ":" + pomSecs;
   }else{
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "COMPLETE";
   }
}

function setTimer(){
   s = 0;
   t = 60*25;
   countDown();
   var timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}
```

The HTML is a basic P tag with the ID of "demo"

Comment: Also, do not use innerHTML since it re-renders the entire DOM. For simple use cases create and append Elements and child nodes.

Comment: huh I didn't know that was a thing. Looks pretty neat, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong way, because your `setInterval` can occur not every 1000ms, but e.g. 1003ms because system was busy and can't execute exactly every 1000ms. That's why `getTime` is more accurate.

Comment: Note that [there is an open issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3151) so that setInterval will self-correct its drift and that [chromium already has this implemented](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/Timer.cpp?rcl=e6d900fb6ed08dbd3a048899f38962ee75f4d8d0&l=162). So in this browser, it wouldn't be as bad as you might think.